# Inkscape or Gimp for creating images for android game?

Tags: android, gimp, inkscape

I'm going to be developing a android game that will be puzzle based so will have a game board with different pieces.  I don't have a lot of experience designing graphics for apps so I was wondering which would be better for developing the game board and various icons and pieces in the game, Inkscape or Gimp?

Comment: This question seems off topic.  It's not related to programming and it's very open-ended and opinionated.

Comment: Heh @helixed, that made me smile `:)`. [opinionated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinionated) != matter of opinion

Comment: How is a question about inkscape and Gimp off topic for a "Gimp" tag and "Inkscape" tag?

Comment: @bien002: because you can write script to these apps, and ask questions about such scripting. Indeed, thequestion is off-topic, but since the answer is short and trivial, not worth the overhead of closing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use InkScape as your base, and convert to raster. 9-patch versus BitMap is more a matter of what you're trying to do with the raster image.

The advantage of InkScape is that you can start with an image and then scale it reasonably well. Vector graphics are good for scaling.

You don't need GIMP, unless you want to scale a raster to a raster. However, I'd avoid scaling rasters unless you absolutely have to. A vector scaling does much better. Always keep the vector as your "master" image, then convert to .png to get a result you can use in Android. It's the graphics equivalent of compilation.

Comment: Actually, GIMP has a couple of effects that are pixel based and would be tough to emulate in vector graphics. If you want any of those, you have to at least do part of your editing GIMP - otherwise, keeping things in vector formats are better.

Comment: If you do use Inkscape I have written an extension that helps you export your assets at multiple resolutions automatically and optionally with the 9-patch borders. You can get it from [Codeplex](http://inkscapeninepatch.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Since the main difference between those two is vector graphics vs. raster. It depends mostly on if you want your images to scale well.

Android  doesn't particularly care which you use, either way you are going to have to export it into an image format that android supports, so assuming the export function of the software is working correctly all image editors are the same as far as Android is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Having been through a similar process for an iOS system I'd say develop the graphics in Inkscape regardless of what your final asset type will be.

In general its far easier to tweak vector graphics than raster graphics.

Then at the end of the process if you really want raster graphics you can export to png.

Answer (score 1):

whatever suit you better? don't forget android 9 patch
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: What in the 9patch image for?

Comment: it is designed to reduce the image size by creating stretchable image.